# The processor does not support XSAVE. This virtual machine cannot be powered on

Tags: vmware, xen

I am getting the below error while installing xenserver on vmware, how to solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl5CH.png)
I have following configs:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBgQ4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4jZB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable Hyper-V which is incompatible with Workstation Pro or Workstation Player.

Go to Control Panel -> Program and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off.

Un-check Hyper-v and click "Ok"

Execute:

bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

In an administrator cmd window

Then restart.